# How to get original destination when redirecting using AuthorizeRouteView

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to get the original destination that the user was navigating to after being redirected to log in.

In my App.razor I have a control that is used when the user is accessing protected content but is not signed in

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin RouteData="@routeData" />
            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorizing>
                <p>Checking that you have a valid access token.</p>
            </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

This redirects the user to an alternate control which then displays the log in page

```
   public class RedirectToLogin : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteData RouteData { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         string url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("/account/login", "redirect_url", "originalDestination");
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
    }
}
```

But what I cant figure out is how to get the original page to redirect the user to after they have logged in. I can see the type in RouteData but there is no path or route values.

Edit:

I've now found a way of getting the path but it doesnt seem the best.
Is this the only way of doing this or am i doing something completly wrong?

```
 var attr = RouteData.PageType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        var route = attr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(RouteAttribute));
        if (route != null)
        {
            _string redirectUri = (route as RouteAttribute).Template;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were doing is a wacky workaround, and problematic. But it's easy to do if one understand how the Blazor routing is manipulated. However, the way to extract the return url; that is the current location (mind you the current location did not change, as you might have thought, as the App component is not part of the routing), is to use the navigation manger in the App component. The following code snippets do the work. Add them to your components.

### Login.razor

```
@page "/login/{returnurl}"


@code {
    // A parameter to get and store the return url
    [Parameter]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

}
```

### App.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager



<NotAuthorized>
 @{
     var returnUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);

      <Login ReturnUrl="@returnUrl" />
  }

 </NotAuthorized>
```

I don't think that any further explanation is needed, but if you have questions, please don't hesitate to ask.